# serve one specific page over http instead of https reactjs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a React app that is running on AWS S3, The website is served over HTTPS.
This website has a page that plays live streams (hosted on other servers) via VideoJS. some stream links(M3U8) work only with HTTP thus resulting in mixed content policy error.

for a workaround, I want this page to be served without an SSL certificate but not sure how to do that. I tried adding a proxy in the package json but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You very likely won't be able to achieve that with S3. The elegant way to do this would be to put an Nginx or similar reverse proxy in front of your webapp and have the proxy serve content as https. If you don't want to host a proxy yourself you could also rely on a third party provider like Cloudflare to sit in front of your webapp and serve everything getting to it as https. Both approaches will work with http servers upstream but serve https content to your viewers, thus eliminating the mixed content warnings in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'll try setting up Cloudflare and get back to you.